# Expand Abstract Java Class for all instances

Tags: java, grails, groovy, metaprogramming

I'm working on a grails application atm. I need a property on an abstract java class (`org.quartz.Trigger`) adding

```
Trigger.metaClass.id = { delegate.hashCode() }
```

before I call the class works. I would like to enable this for all my Triggers in my application. Is this possible? Or do I have to repeat this everytime I need the property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add to the `metaClass` before any `Trigger` objects are instantiated, then this addition will exist in all of them.

However, after they are created, you would need to add it to every instance of `Trigger`.

Of course, this method will only be visible from Groovy, as Java does not know about the `metaClass`.

Some example Groovy code showing this in action:

```
// Add to the metaClass of an anstract java class
AbstractList.metaClass.woo = { 'hi there' }

// Create an instance of a class that extends this abstract class
ArrayList list = [ 1, 2, 3 ]

// Call the closure in the metaClass
println list.woo()
```

Comment: Thanks tim. By adding it to my BootStrap.groovy in my grails Environment dynamic generated methods and properties are accessible in my whole application.